# Bootstrap 3 need white Space input group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

in bootstrap 3 i want an input in one row by grouping the input i done it but the space is not occurring can any one help http://jsfiddle.net/qkPEm/1/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="dd" class="location" name="city" type="text" placeholder="Source" size="90" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="geocomplete" class="location" name="city" type="text" placeholder="Destination" size="90" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="input-append form-date" readonly="true" type="text" id="dpd1" placeholder="From" value="" name="arrival" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="input-append form-date" readonly="true" type="text" id="dpd2" placeholder="To" value="" name="departure" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="guests" class="date" readonly="true" type="text" id="tags2" placeholder="Ttl.Expenses" value="" name="guests" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the row inside a <div class="container">?

Comment: ys it is inside jumbotron and container

Comment: Can you put the css in here? can't reproduce your situation without css. I found out that the size for each input are somehow affected the output without any css. http://www.bootply.com/K9O1ZJTLwQ

Comment: here i update the link with css http://www.bootply.com/CcKaV6hqha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input size causing the issues.

Here's my method on solving the white space.

http://www.bootply.com/PRnJqqD8S3

Your input size is way over the col-lg-2's width, that's why you got the extra spacing.